# First page number settings

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, thesis

I want the page number (and layout) for the first page to be the same as for the following ones, but with this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}            
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}    
\usepackage[margin=3cm,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\small{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\small{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
```

The number in the first page is always centred and I don't get the head/footrule (I would like to set only the foot one).

Does anyone know how to deal with it? Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please expand your code to a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Read in the documentation of fancyhdr section 7 "Redefining plain style."

Comment: If I compile your document, adding just `\usepackage{lipsum}` and `\begin{document} \lipsum \end{document}` then I get the page numbers exactly where you indicated them.  Do you have something like a title page?  Regardless, like @Bobyandbob said, please provide a minimal working example.